# How get a Python pathlib Path from an Azure blob datastore?

Tags: python, azure, pytorch, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to do some custom manipulation of a `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` in AzureML but cannot get it to instantiate directly from my `azureml.core.Datastore` :

```
ws = Workspace( # ... etc ... )
ds = Datastore.get(ws, datastore_name='my_ds')
am = ds.as_mount()

# HOW DO I GET base_path, data_file from am?

dataloader = DataLoader(
        ListDataset(base_path, data_file), #... etc...
    )
```

The value of `am.path()` is "$AZUREML_DATAREFERENCE_my_ds" but I cannot figure out how to go from that to a `pathlib.Path` as is expected by the constructor to `ListDataset`. Things I've tried include `Path(am.path())` and `Path(os.environ[am.path()])` but they don't seem to work.

It's clear that there's *some* answer, since :

```
script_params = {
    '--base_path': ds.as_mount(), 
    '--epochs': 30,  
    '--batch_size' : 16,  
    '--use_cuda': 'true'
}
torch = PyTorch(source_directory='./',
                        script_params=script_params,
                        compute_target=compute_target,
                        entry_script='train.py',
                        pip_packages=packages,
                        use_gpu=True)
```

seems to create a legit object.

Comment: You mean we have to pass the DataReference object through an estimator to access data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perhaps try using the [DataPath class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.datapath.datapath?view=azure-ml-py). It exposes attributes such as `path_on_datastore` which might be the path you're looking for.

To construct this class from your DataReference object i.e. variable `am`; you can use  `create_from_data_reference()` method.

Example:

```py
ds = Datastore.get(ws, datastore_name='my_ds')
am = ds.as_mount()

dp = DataPath().create_from_data_reference(am)

base_path = dp.path_on_datastore
```

Answer (score 1):

The above code generated an error for me, removing the parentheses after the DataPath instantiation like below made the code run.

```
ds = Datastore.get(ws, datastore_name='my_ds')
am = ds.as_mount()

dp = DataPath.create_from_data_reference(am)

base_path = dp.path_on_datastore
```

Thank you for the code snippet, very useful!

Comment: Hi Karin, do you know what could possibly be the reason for getting a None value for base_path?