# Access data on AML datastore from training script

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am looking for a working example how to access data on a [Azure Machine Learning managed data store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-access-data#access-datastores-during-training) from within a train.py script. I followed the instructions in the link and my script is able to resolve the datastore.

However, whatever I tried (`as_download(), as_mount()`) the only thing I always got was a [DataReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.data_reference.datareference?view=azure-ml-py) object. Or maybe I just don't understand how actually read data from a file with that.

```
run = Run.get_context()
exp = run.experiment
ws = run.experiment.workspace

ds = Datastore.get(ws, datastore_name='mydatastore')
data_folder_mount = ds.path('mnist').as_mount()

# So far this all works. But how to go from here?
```

Comment: I have always used those DataReferences as variables inside a `script_params` variable to create an Estimator object, a bit as indicated in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/how-to-access-data#examples . When you say "access" are  you aiming at downloading the contents locally instead?

Comment: Maybe this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/55884641/4240413 is similar (not a duplicate though?) to that of the OP here.

Comment: Downloads data from a datastore into a local directory, Please refer the following link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-cli-ml/ml/datastore?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-azure-cli-ml-az-ml-datastore-download)

Comment: Thanks @Ram but your link refers to the CLI, I’m looking for guidance on the python sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in the DataReference object you created as the input to your training product (scriptrun/estimator/hyperdrive/pipeline). Then in your training script, you can access the mounted path via argument.
full tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/service/tutorial-train-models-with-aml

Comment: Thanks! In the meantime I made it work using this tutorial: https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-how-to-use-estimatorstep.ipynb But I'll accept your answer nevertheless